# Will electron repulse by superconductor or at least change trajectory?

Tags: electrons, superconductivity

Suppose we have an electron gun which is bombarding superconductor. Would the  electron get repelled or change its trajectory? It is well known that electrons are sources of magnetic fields. Also it is well known that superconductor is impenetrable to weak magnetic fields (Meissner effect).

Comment: I was asking myself exactly the same question!

Answer (score 0):

Since superconductor is a conductor of electricity, the electric field of the electron should repel electrons in the superconductor, thus making the superconducor itself have an electric field that attracts the electron.